# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a noetherian ring

Tags: ring-theory

**Claim**: the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a noetherian ring

**My proof**

1) $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

2) $\mathbb{Z}$ is a noetherian ring.

3) Every finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is a noetherian module, hence $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a noetherian $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

4) By definition of noetherian module, every $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module

5) an ideal $\mathfrak{i}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is in particular a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

6) $\mathfrak{i}=\mathbb{Z}x_1+\ldots +\mathbb{Z}x_n$

7) since $\mathfrak{i}$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is also finitely generated as an ideal

Do you think my proof works?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to prove directly that the Gaussian integers are an euclidean domain and thus *even* a PID?

Comment: @DonAntonio you are surely right, but here i'm just wondering if there is some mathematical absurdity in my proof

Comment: The first point is interesting (and true, don't worry), but: how do *you* know $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ is a f.g. abelian group = f.g. $\,\Bbb Z$-module) ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I show that $1,i$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis

Comment: I think you can apply Hilbert-basis theorem, with the fact that quotients of the noetherian domains are noetherian. But I think that this is essentially your approach.

Comment: Since your proof does not use much of $\Bbb Z[i]$, you should try to prove something more general (like any ring $\Bbb Z[a]$ for an algebraic element $a$, or even $\Bbb Z[a,b,\ldots,x]$ is Noetherian), as long as it doesn't require any fundamental change in the proof. If something is wrong with the proof, you may generalise to something manifestly untrue and thus detect the error, if not you've got a more interesting result.

Comment: This looks correct to me, but from the way you've written it I can't help feeling that you're unsure about what to do at steps 6 and 7. You've picked a Z-generating set for your ideal I; now just show that the same elements generate the same ideal over Z[i]. (You'll need to use the fact that I is a Z[i]-ideal, of course.) More generally, if $A\subseteq B$ are any two rings, and $I$ is an ideal of $B$ which is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then any set of $A$-generators for $I$ will also be a set of $B$-generators for $I$ (but not necessarily conversely) - can you see why?

Comment: @bateman, how did you know you could take only two elements and *precisely* those one? I'm trying to reach a point here...

Comment: @Billy i'm probably missing something, because what you say seems to me absolutely obvious, but i suspect it is not. You say that I have a set of $A$- generators for $I$. Well, $A$ is contained in $B$, hence that is also a set of $B$-generators for $I$. What am i missing?

Comment: @DonAntonio By definition of gaussian integer as a number of the form $a+ib$ i get that $1,i$ is a set of generators for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. For linear indipendence, i suppose $a+ib=0$ and the only way this can happen is $a=0=b$...but probably you was asking me something different..

Comment: Well, what I tried to arrive to is that when you take, for example $\,\alpha\in\Bbb C\;$ , then $\,\Bbb Z[\alpha]\;$ is a finitely generated $\,\Bbb Z$-module iff $\,\alpha\,$ is *integral* over $\,\Bbb Z\,$, which in this case is true. Apparently you saw a different, simpler definition which is alright to work with.

Comment: @bateman Your argument in 6 and 7 is not *written down* in a completely watertight way. This could be because a) you don't understand it, b) you have an intuitive idea of what's going on but can't write it down, or c) it's very obvious and you didn't need to write it down. So I don't know whether you find this obvious or not, or what 'kind' of obvious you find it. :) Anyway: if $X$ is your $A$-generating set, then $I = AX$ by definition. Then $AX\subseteq BX$, because $A\subseteq B$. But $BX\subseteq BI$, because $X\subseteq I$. And $I$ is an ideal of $B$, so $BI = I$ by definition. So $BX=I$.

Comment: @Billy now it's very clear to me, thanks for making all steps explicit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you like another proof?

By Hilbert's Theorem $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is noetherian. Hence $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is also noetherian as a factor-ring of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

**Addendum:** In fact, here (for one unknown) Hilbert's theorem is not needed.

Comment: As short, simple and elegant as one can expect. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you.